# Error closing PyQT app, after app.exec() returns

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Every time a simple PyQT GUI is quit from a QT Button, I see an error: `Must construct a QGuiApplication first.` The error comes after running the application for any amount of time, but only if a button is clicked which triggers `Qt.quit()`. If the app is stopped by closing the window, there is no error. So far, I've only tested on Ubuntu Artful, with PyQT packages from Ubuntu.

The simplest app to demonstrate this is:

### test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import PyQt5.QtCore as QtCore
import PyQt5.QtGui as QtGui
import PyQt5.QtQml as QtQml



def main():
    ''' setup and run the application '''

    # Create the application instance.
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])

    # Create a QML engine.
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine(parent=app)

    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl('test.qml'))

    app.exec()

    print('a')   # <--- This is printed before the QT error message
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    print('b')
```

### test.qml

```
import QtQuick 2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4


ApplicationWindow {
    id: main_window
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "Quit"
        onClicked: Qt.quit()
    }
}
```

### output

```
a
Must construct a QGuiApplication first.
b
```

The error comes after `app.exec()` finishes, but before `main()` returns.

Is there something else that needs to be done to shutdown PyQT cleanly?

Comment: One solution is to define the app as a global variable: `app = None`  `def main():` `global app` `app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])`

Comment: Thanks, @eyllanesc , that gets rid of the error. It's an awkward way to do it though. Is there something missing from how I'm shutting down QT?

Comment: What happens is that the app is a local variable, and python needs to remove it, but in your case, as a local app, it has already been deleted. the section of the main I put it directly in `if __name__ == '__main __':`, I mean the following: `if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl('test.qml'))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep most functionality inside `main()`, the best solution is to move the QGuiApplication() outside of all functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import PyQt5.QtCore as QtCore
import PyQt5.QtGui as QtGui
import PyQt5.QtQml as QtQml



def main(app):
    ''' setup and run the application '''

    # Create a QML engine.
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine(parent=app)

    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl('test.qml'))

    app.exec()

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the application instance.
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    main(app)
```

This exits cleanly, but I'd still like to know how to fully shut down PyQT. I think the problem is that there are still events in an event loop that are trying to run after `app.exec()` returns, but I haven't found how to let them run to completion and stop.

Thank you eyllanesc for your help.